# java Script User Define $ function like jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to Create user define $ function as i cannot use Jquery in existing project.

I want to get this function as work as Jquery $('ID')

Please give me some hint Any hint OR Example
for Example

```
function $(element) {

}

var value = $('elementID').value
```

**UPDATE:**
As i have prototype.js

```
function $(element) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)
      elements.push($(arguments[i]));
    return elements;
  }
  if (Object.isString(element))
    element = document.getElementById(element);
  return Element.extend(element);
}
```

Comment: No. As we are using own prototype.js

Comment: Since you're using Prototype [you already have the function you're looking for.](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with:

```
function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

**However**, you'll eventually find that that is not good enough. Internet Explorer (in older versions), it turns out, returns values by **name** too.  In other words, if there's an element on the page whose "name" attribute matches the "id" you're looking for, you (might) get that instead.

Thus, you have to actually do more work than that. I recommend checking the source to jQuery or Prototype to find the state-of-the-art way that smart people are dealing with that problem. *edit* wow in jQuery it's fairly complicated.

Comment: Yes, we are using prototype.js

Comment: Well if you're using Prototype then you've already got the function; you don't have to do anything.

Comment: so `Object.isString(element)` i would not go at `element = document.getElementById(element);` it enters in first condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
function $(element) {
     return document.getElementById(element);
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/UkMAE/

Answer (score 2):

1. advice - check jQuery source code - very readable and would give you a hint how to implent it.

2.for modern browsers you can implent this using behind the scene:

```
var x =document.querySelector(selector)
```

and querySelectorAll(selector)

edit: yes - getElementById would work if you only look for id, if you need more complex css selectors - you could use this.  jQuery defaults to querySelector when it's supported

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Sizzle library if you only want selectors like jQuery: http://sizzlejs.com/

And then do the following in your code:

```
var $ = Sizzle;
```

Now you can use:

```
$("selector");
```

Answer (score 1):

My JS:

```
var $ = function(element) {
    element = document.getElementById(element);
    return {
        "0": element,
        "val": function(text) {
            if ( text ) {
                console.log(this);
                this[0].value = text;
                return this;
            } else {
                return this[0].value;
            }
        }
    };
}

onload = function() {
    var myElement = $("someID");
    alert(myElement.val("some value").val());
}
```

---

My DOM:

```
<input id="someID">
```